# How to generate API docs from .json descriptor file?

Tags: json, node.js, api

I have generated a `node.js` application skeleton using Restlet studio. This skeleton contains a `swagger2.json` definition file, which contains roughly all API information that I'd like to have. Is there any straightforward way to display those information as docs, in a more readable format? I have researched and found stuff like `swagger.io`, not quite sure how to use it though, even after looking through the documentation.

Edit: I copied all files from `dist` folder into my root application folder, then modified `index.html`:

```
var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
  if (url && url.length > 1) {
    url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
  } else {
    url = "json/swagger2.json"; //I replaced here with my json
  }
```

however, when I launch it in my browser, all I get is:

```
Please specify the protocol for file:///home/osboxes/Desktop/nodejsServerSkeleton_3/index.html/json/swagger2.json
```

In other words, can I do it for a local `swagger.json` file? Or only for publicly accessible resources?

Comment: How about [Swagger UI](http://petstore.swagger.io/) for documentation?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I aim to see. I have no clue though how to do it for my node project.

Comment: It's really easy, just copy all the files from their [repo](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) to your node app's public folder. Then update index.html file with your swagger2.json

Comment: `file:///...` you are accessing the index.html file through your file explorer. Try visit from your server url like `http://localhost:3000/api/index.html` - assuming you copied the files in /api directory under your node project.